# How to write a function for validating inputs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of inputs. I store them in Vuex state. Each input has a regex validation. I need to write a function which checking if there is an error or not. If no errors it's redirect to another page, if any no action  until you fix them. Thats how looks my Vuex State

[image]

Here is my function , but it does not work correctly. It checks once , if I fix all errors , it doesn't redirect to the next page

```
submitForm() {
  const { textfield, textfieldsRight } = this.$store.state.stepOne
  let errorArray = textfield.concat(textfieldsRight)
  let i
  for (i = 0; errorArray.length > i; i++) {
    if (errorArray[i].errors) {
      return
    } else {
      this.$router.push("/finish")
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Are you empting `textfield.concat(textfieldsRight)` after each submit, and before refilling it with the errors?

Comment: @Sirence no , should I ?

Comment: Since you save the state in store, you will always have all previous errors in it, even after fixing them in your input. Make sure you empty it after the submit, then immediatly refill it with the new data, so you only get the new errors, if there are any.

Comment: @Sirence Can you please give me any idea how to do it?

Comment: Can you make an example with some data in this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/6vpuwxd8/ I would need to see your inputs to help further.